# How to install Perl on Ubuntu Server?

Tags: ubuntu, perl

I'm trying to deploy an application which according to the documentation requires the following:

```
2.2.5. Perl

LMS-MGC and the rest of Perl scripts requires also Perl interpreter and some modules:

Perl and its basic modules (POSIX, GetOpt::Long),

Config::IniFiles,

DBI,

DBD-mysql (if you use MySQL),

DBD-Pg (if you use Postgres),
```

How do I install the requirements with [apt-get](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Advanced_Packaging_Tool#Usage)?

Answer (score 10):

The Ubuntu package for Perl is simply "perl":

```
sudo apt-get install perl
```

which I think is preinstalled.

To find a Perl module that's provided as an Ubuntu package:

```
apt-cache search perl <module-name>
```

For example:

```
$ apt-cache search perl Config::IniFiles
libconfig-inifiles-perl - Read .ini-style configuration files
$ apt-cache search perl DBD-mysql
libdbd-mysql-perl - Perl5 database interface to the MySQL database
$ apt-cache search perl DBD-Pg
libdbd-pg-perl - Perl DBI driver for the PostgreSQL database server
```

I've skipped `apt-cache search perl DBI` because it produces 112 lines of output.  The Ubuntu package name for that follows the others, and is `libdbi-perl`.

Then use `sudo apt-get install ...` to install each package.  You should be able to use a single `apt-get` command to install all of them.

Answer (score 1):

The packages are sometimes different in different versions. Perl package names are similar with module names. You can start from [Ubuntu Packages Search](http://packages.ubuntu.com/), espexially "Search the contents of packages" is useful if you do not know package name but know its contents. For example Config::IniFiles should have file IniFiles.pm in directory Config. Choose your Ubuntu version, enter "IniFiles.pm" and you'll get package name.

Answer (score 0):

You could install Perl normally using `apt-get` and then use [Perl package manager](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perl_package_manager) (command `ppm`) to install the rest.

Comment: What commands might you need to run to get this result?

Comment: PPM is primarily used on Windows systems. It is not necessary, or desirable, on Linux systems. Use apt-get or CPAN to install Perl modules.